# Subsetting data from checkbox in Shiny to create bar graph and pie chart

Tags: r, shiny

I am fairly new to Shiny (and R in general) and have been struggling with creating an app that can subset data by reserve, category, use type, and years in order to create a bar graph of use over time and a pie chart which averages use between each of the three categories. Here is an example of what my data looks like:

```
Reserve Category    Users   UserDays    Year
S       Research    31       9735        2002
S       Education   71       77          2002
S       Public      0         0          2002
S       Research    58       21596       2003
S       Education   387      509         2003
S       Public      188      219         2003
V       Research    43       642         2012
V       Education   12        60        2012
V       Public      874       2882       2012
V       Research    51        458        2013
V       Education   27        108        2013
V       Public     1003       1932       2013
```

And here is what my code looks like currently:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


ReserveData <- read_csv("DataTotals.csv")
View(ReserveData)


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Data Analysis"), 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Reserve", "Reserve:", choices = c("S", "V")),
      selectInput("UseStatistic", "Use Statistic:", choices = c("Users",     "UserDays")),
      checkboxGroupInput("Category", label = h3("Category"), 
                     choices = list("Research" = 1, "Education" = 2, "Public" = 3),selected = 1),
      hr(),
      fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("Category"))), 
      fluidRow(
        column(4,
               sliderInput("Years", label = h3("Years"), min = 2002, 
                       max = 2017, value = c(2002, 2017))
        )
      ),

      hr(),
      fluidRow(
        column(4, verbatimTextOutput("value")),
        column(4, verbatimTextOutput("Years")))

    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("Categories"),
      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot"),
      plotOutput("distPie")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$Categories <- renderTable({
    ReserveDATA <- filter(ReserveData, Reserve == input$Reserve)
    ReserveDATA <- filter(ReserveDATA, Year >= input$Years[1] & Year <=   input$Years[2])
    if(is.null(input$Category))
      return()
    Reserve_Data <- ReserveDATA[input$Category, ]
    Reserve_Data
  })
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    ReserveDATA <- filter(ReserveData, Reserve == input$Reserve)
    ReserveDATA <- filter(ReserveDATA, Year >= input$Years[1] & Year <=    input$Years[2])
    if(is.null(input$Category))
      return()
    Reserve_Data <- ReserveDATA[input$Category, ]
    ggplot(data = Reserve_Data, aes(x=Year, y = input$UseStatistic, fill = Category)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge())
  })
  output$distPie <- renderPlot({
    ReserveDATA <- filter(ReserveData, Reserve == input$Reserve)
    ReserveDATA <- filter(ReserveDATA, Year >= input$Years[1] & Year <=    input$Years[2])
    pie(ReserveDATA$Users, labels = ReseveDATA$Category)

  })
 }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I can't figure out why when I am trying to subset by category, I only get the first year displayed and not all years I am looking at. Additionally, when I am trying to have my bar graph with users and user days displayed, instead of displaying the number from that column, I only get a graph with the words users or user days displayed (instead of the actual data). And I currently don't have anything showing up for my pie chart.

Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues in your code starting from filters to typo while using the name `ReserveDATA`. I've tried to reduce it by Data Filtering part into a separate `reactive`. It's always a better practice to check your filters in your RStudio (console session) before using it inside Shiny and that makes debugging easier and also will make sure that the filters work in the first place. And try using `%>%` operator while filter since that's something that `tidyverse` offers to make the data pipeline readable and prettier. And finally, I've replaced your
`aes` inside `ggplot` with `aes_string` to get string input (that comes directly from your shiny ui)

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


ReserveData <- read_csv("DataTotals.csv")
##View(ReserveData)


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Data Analysis"), 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Reserve", "Reserve:", choices = c("S", "V")),
      selectInput("UseStatistic", "Use Statistic:", choices = c("Users",     "UserDays")),
      checkboxGroupInput("Category", label = h3("Category"), 
                         choices = list("Research" , "Education" , "Public" ),selected = 'Research'),
      hr(),
      fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("Category"))), 
      fluidRow(
        column(4,
               sliderInput("Years", label = h3("Years"), min = 2002, 
                           max = 2017, value = c(2002, 2017))
        )
      ),

      hr(),
      fluidRow(
        column(4, verbatimTextOutput("value")),
        column(4, verbatimTextOutput("Years")))

    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("Categories"),
      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot"),
      plotOutput("distPie")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  ReserveDATA <- reactive({
    ReserveDATA <- ReserveData %>% filter(Reserve %in% input$Reserve) %>%
      filter(Category %in% input$Category) %>%
      filter(Year >= input$Years[1] & Year <= input$Years[2])
    #cat(input$Years)
    #ReserveDATA <- filter(ReserveData, Reserve == input$Reserve)
    #ReserveDATA <- filter(ReserveDATA, Year >= input$Years[1] & Year <=   input$Years[2])
    if(is.null(input$Category))
      return()
    #Reserve_Data <- ReserveDATA[input$Category, ]
    ReserveDATA
  })


  output$Categories <- renderTable({
    ReserveDATA()

  })
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({


    ggplot(data = ReserveDATA(), aes_string(x='Year', y = input$UseStatistic, fill = 'Category')) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge())
  })
  output$distPie <- renderPlot({ 
    pie(ReserveDATA()$Users, labels = ReserveDATA()$Category)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

First issue:

`checkboxGroupInput` returns the value of the options checked, not their labels. Therefore, when you check "Research" you get the value "1" in `input$Category`and not "Research" as you seem to expect when you try to subset like this: `Reserve_Data <- ReserveDATA[input$Category, ]`. Also, subsetting like that will not work. So, to fix the first issue, you can replace

```
Reserve_Data <- ReserveDATA[input$Category, ]
```

with

```
Category_selected <- c( "1"="Research", "2"="Education" , "3"= "Public")[input$Category]
    Reserve_Data <- filter(ReserveDATA,Category==Category_selected)
```

Second issue:

`input$UseStatistic` returns a string, `aes` does not understand strings as column names and therefore, ggplot just displays your string. To solve that problem you could replace:

```
ggplot(data = Reserve_Data, aes(x=Year, y = input$UseStatistic, fill = Category)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge())
```

with

```
 to.plot <- Reserve_Data  %>% mutate(Year=factor(Year)) %>% rename_(UseStatistic=input$UseStatistic)

 ggplot(data = to.plot , aes(x=Year, y = UseStatistic, fill = Category)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge())
```

So, to summarise, your issues are solved if you replace:

```
 output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    ReserveDATA <- filter(ReserveData, Reserve == input$Reserve)
    ReserveDATA <- filter(ReserveDATA, Year >= input$Years[1] & Year <=    input$Years[2])
    if(is.null(input$Category))
      return()
    Reserve_Data <- ReserveDATA[input$Category, ]
    ggplot(data = Reserve_Data, aes(x=Year, y = input$UseStatistic, fill = Category)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge())
  })
```

with

```
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    ReserveDATA <- filter(ReserveData, Reserve == input$Reserve)

    ReserveDATA <- filter(ReserveDATA, Year >= input$Years[1] & Year <=    input$Years[2])

    if(is.null(input$Category))
      return()

    Category_selected <- c( "1"="Research", "2"="Education" , "3"= "Public")[input$Category]
    Reserve_Data <- filter(ReserveDATA,Category==Category_selected)

    to.plot <- Reserve_Data  %>% mutate(Year=factor(Year)) %>% rename_(UseStatistic=input$UseStatistic)

    ggplot(data = to.plot , aes(x=Year, y = UseStatistic, fill = Category)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge())
  })
```

Finally, there is a typo. This line:

```
pie(ReserveDATA$Users, labels = ReseveDATA$Category)
```

should read

```
pie(ReserveDATA$Users, labels = ReserveDATA$Category)
```